# How do I scale tkinter canvas window without changing objects

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

How do I scale a Tkinter canvas itself. I am creating an application where it would be far more elegant ( that is to say much more readable) if I can plot things on a tkinter canvas in engineering units (inches) and simply scale the canvas to the window. The attached code is quite over simplified for what I want to to but I believe that it gets the point across. I would like to apply the scale factor once instead of each and every time I add an object to the canvas. I would like the canvas to represent 36 inches (or whatever) and be scaled so that 36 inches is 1800 pixels wide (or whatever window width). Once established this scale factor would not change.
(I know that if self.canvas.coords(thing)[2]>canvaswidth will have to change as well).

I have seen this asked in different forms but I have not found an answer that does not involve scaling all the widgits on the canvas. I think it would be rather in-elegant to have a global scale factor and sprinkle it everywhere that I used a canvas coordinate.

```
#AP moving machine
from Tkinter import *
MagicNumber=0.3125
MN=MagicNumber*7
PunchPositions=([MN*1,2],[MN*2,4],[MN*3,2],[MN*4,4])
PiercePositions=([MN*5,2],[MN*6,4],[MN*7,2],[MN*8,4])
class mover():
    def __init__(self,root,canvas,things):
        self.things=things
        self.canvas=canvas
        self.root=root
        self.root.after(100,self.move)
        self.counter=0
    def addoval(self,x,y):
        r=0.125
        self.things.append(canvas.create_oval(x-r,y-r,x+r,y+r,fill='green'))
    def addpierce(self,x,y):
        r=0.0625
        self.things.append(canvas.create_oval(x-r,y-r,x+r,y+r,fill='Black'))

    def move(self):
        for thing in self.things:
            canvas.move(thing,1.250)
        canvaswidth=canvas.winfo_width()
        for thing in self.things:
            if self.canvas.coords(thing)[2]>canvaswidth :
                self.canvas.delete(thing)
                self.things.remove(thing)
        root.after(100,self.move)
        self.counter=self.counter+1
        for x,y in PunchPositions:
            self.addoval(x,y)
        for x,y in PiercePositions:
            self.addpierce(x,y)
#
root =Tk()
canvas=Canvas(root,width=1800,height=200)
parts=[]

def AddPierce(x,y):
    radius=0.125
    x1=x-radius
    x2=x+radius
    y1=y-radius
    y2=y+radius
    return canvas.create_oval(x1,y1,x2,y2,fill='Black')
def AddPunch(x,y):
    radius=0.250
    x1=x-radius
    x2=x+radius
    y1=y-radius
    y2=y+radius
    return canvas.create_oval(x1,y1,x2,y2,fill='Blue')

for x,y in PunchPositions:
    AddPunch(x,y)
for x,y in PiercePositions:
    AddPierce(x,y)

for l in range(1,12):
    canvas.create_line(l*MagicNumber*4,0,l*MagicNumber*4,6)

canvas.pack(fill=BOTH)
mover(root,canvas,parts)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot scale the items in a canvas without modifying the objects themselves. The only feature that the canvas supplies is the `scale` method, but it works by changing the actual coordinates of the items.